# DropDownListFor always return null to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
    {
        public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ChooseProject")]
    public ActionResult ChooseProject(Project projects)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Application");
    }
```

And finally my view:

```
@using ServicePortal.Web.Controllers
@model ServicePortal.Web.Models.ProjectViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Choose project";
}

<div class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChooseProject", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="innerForm formgroup">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "" })

            @Html.DropDownListFor((model => model.Projects), new SelectList(Model.Projects,"ProjectKey", "ProjectName"))

            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="button pull-right">Go on</button>,
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

The dropdownlist is populated with the correct values, but I would like to return either a Project or a string with ProjectKey to the controller. However, when I submit the form and check the value in the parameter in the controller, it is always null, both when I try to return a Project and when I try with string. I don't get any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public string SelectedProjectKey { get; set; }  // string may need to be int depending on what type ProjectKey is in your class
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor((model => model.SelectedProjectKey), new SelectList(Model.Projects,"ProjectKey", "ProjectName"))
```

Your controller action:

```
public ActionResult ChooseProject(ProjectViewModel model)
```

This will get you the key of whatever project you selected in model.SelectedProjectKey and you can use that in your controller chooseproject action method to do whatever you intended.